# How to check if request header exists with javascript fetch

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Here's my code in a Chrome extension:

```
fetch(finalURL).then((response) => {
    if(response.status === 200){
        chrome.tabs.create({url: `https://example.com/?redirect=${domain[0]}`, active: false});
    }
}).catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

I'm want to check to see if the response status is set too 200 and check to see if the **request** header `accept-encoding` was sent the fetch request.

I've added the code for checking if the status is 200, but can't figure out how to check request headers.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Request headers would be passed just after url in fetch like `fetch(url, {headers: {}})`. I don't think you'll find them in the response.

Comment: You can see the outgoing headers in chrome.webRequest.onHeadersSent event, see the documentation. P.S. register it in extraHeaders mode to obtain all headers.

Answer (score 0):

if you can check the header of the incoming response if it has that specific property as such:

```
if(response.status === 200 && response.headers.has('accept-encoding')){
        // your code
}
```

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers

Something to keep in mind is that headers are case-insensitive. You may want to change it to lower case before checking.

```
From RFC 2616 - "Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1", Section 4.2, "Message Headers":

Each header field consists of a name followed by a colon (":") and the field value. Field names are case-insensitive.
```

ref: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2